# VIrtual Keyboard, every button pressed when I want to press one

Tags: python, opencv, virtual-keyboard

```
import cv2
from cvzone.HandTrackingModule import HandDetector
import mediapipe
import numpy as np
import cvzone
from pynput.keyboard import Controller
from time import sleep

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(9, 1920)
cap.set(16,720)

detector = HandDetector(detectionCon=1)

keys = [["Q", "W", "E", "R", "T", "Y", "U", "I", "O", "P"],
        ["A", "S", "D", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "L", ";"],
        ["Z", "X", "C", "V", "B", "N", "M", ",", ".", "/"]]
finalText=""

keyboard = Controller()

def drawALL(img, buttonList):
    for button in buttonList:
       x, y = button.pos
       w, h = button.size
       cv2.rectangle(img, button.pos, (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
       cv2.putText(img, button.text, (x + 20, y + 65), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 4, (255, 255, 255), 4)

    return img
class Button():
    def __init__(self, pos, text, size=[85,85]):
        self.pos = pos
        self.size = size
        self.text = text


buttonList = []
for i in range(len(keys)):
    for j, key in enumerate(keys[i]):
        buttonList.append(Button([100 * j + 50, 100 * i + 50], key))


while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    img = detector.findHands(img)
    lmList, bboxInfo = detector.findPosition(img)
    img = drawALL(img, buttonList)

    if lmList:
        for button in buttonList:
            x, y = button.pos
            w, h = button.size

            if x < lmList[8][0] < x + w and y<lmList[8][1] < y + h:
                cv2.rectangle(img, button.pos, (x + w, y + h), (175, 0, 175), cv2.FILLED)
                cv2.putText(img, button.text, (x + 20, y + 65),
                            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 4, (255, 255, 255), 4)
            l, _, _ = detector.findDistance(8 ,12 , img, draw=False)
            print(l)

            if l<30: #problem can be here
                cv2.rectangle(img, button.pos, (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), cv2.FILLED)
                cv2.putText(img, button.text, (x + 20, y + 65), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 4, (255, 255, 255), 4)
                finalText += button.text
                sleep(0.15)

            cv2.rectangle(img, (50,350), (700, 450), (175, 0, 175), cv2.FILLED)
            cv2.putText(img, finalText, (60,425),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 4, (255, 255, 255), 4)


    cv2.imshow("Image", img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Wrote a code for virtual keyboard by a video lesson and caught an error that every button on my keyboard pressed when I want to press one, this problem starts after `if l<30:`.

How to fix this?